# How to run 'polymer build' in visualstudio.com

Tags: polymer, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

[image]

I could, after a lot of effort, create a step in the job where I install (correctly) the polymer CLI.

Now I would like to build my client project, but I tried with command lines, npm commands, whatever, I couldn't find the correct definition to obtain a proper build.

In this picture, I show the error that happens in the command line 'polymer build'.

[image]

How could I obtain the desired result?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you try to specify a full path to the tool? Did you try running just the command "polymer" with the *argument* "build"?

Comment: Please add a screen shot of the run polimer build task. Try to add a build variable system.debug (value true) and run your build again. Add the resulting log to your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Tool** is `polymer` and **Arguments** is `build`:

[image]

Comment: Now I have to investigate my build problems :-) but it works! Really thank you!